# How do you give an .exe an ico image in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, icons

I have the application using an .ico image for the taskbar and window, but how do you set up the .exe to use an icon?

While on this subject does anyone have any resources on how to work with ico images? As in what size does the start bar use, and so forth?

From what I can find there are tools out there to assign .exe's icon images but this is surely  not the correct way of doing things.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can change the application icon from Common Properties -> General -> Application Icon

Comment: Such a simple thing, such an obvious place yet I totally ignore it. Thanks.

Comment: I was curious about this too: In Visual Studio 2008, I found this setting by going to the project properties and selecting the Application tab. Under Icon and Manifest, there is a choice of icon. I am wondering if this is the same as what you suggest.

Comment: Yeah, that's where I found it.

Comment: Yay! Now all my apps will look pretty!

Answer (score 2):

Here are guidelines to the Vista standard for icons.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511280.aspx

Answer (score 1):

For the edition of icons, I use [IcoFx](http://icofx.ro/), which is free, and served my needs well (definition of icon at all sizes, transparency).

Answer (score 1):

If your are using Visual Studio 2013, you can:
1. Right click on your project and select properties.
2. In the new tab it opens, you can find the "icon and manifest" under Application tab where you can set the new icon

Answer (score 0):

To work with .ico images I use [Axialis Icon Workshop](http://www.axialis.com/iconworkshop/).

It can create or manipulate Vista Icons, XP Icons, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As for icon creation/edit resources, I usually just use GIMP.  It's probably not the best tool for the job but it's free and easy to use.